# Tab Bar Controller - Adding more Items in tab bar looks messy

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

I am developing an application which has more than five tab bar items. while running application it looks so messy.
Can anyone suggest me what should I do?
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DalB3.png)

This is the screenshot. In this image for now I have added only 4 items but I am going to add more items. Please help me.

Thank You

Comment: Welcome to SO. Do you have a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that you'd be willing to post?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/x7g24up6eui8sda/Adding_More_tabs.zip?dl=0

Comment: This is the sample project @ Richard Erickson When I run this in iPhone 4s it looks so messy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use some custom Tabbarcontrollers.

Please check below link. There are some of the controls with more tab items and scrolling.

https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?q=tabbar